# Time complexity of a function in python with nested loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

Why is it O(n^6)? and not O(n^9)?

```
def fa1(n):
    k = 0
    for i in range(1, (n ** 6) + 1) :
        for j in range(i * 3, (n ** 3) + 1):
            k += 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Because it's `n**3`, not `i**3`

Comment: Still not getting it.. could you please elaborate?

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong. It should be O(n^9).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a computation that is `O(n^6)` is also `O(n^9)` (`n >= 0`), by defintion of the [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). The latter is just a poorer approximation.

Second, it's trivial if you rewrite your function like this:

```
def fa1(n):
    k = 0
    for i in range(1, ((n ** 3) + 1)//3 + 1) :
        for j in range(i * 3, (n ** 3) + 1):
            k += 1

    for i in range(((n ** 3) + 1)//3 + 1, (n ** 6) + 1) :
        for j in range(i * 3, (n ** 3) + 1):
            k += 1
```

The second loop has always `i * 3 >= (n ** 3) + 1`, hence the inner loop is skipped because the `range` is empty. The function is thus equivalent to:

```
def fa1(n):
    k = 0
    for i in range(1, ((n ** 3) + 1)//3 + 1) :
        for j in range(i * 3, (n ** 3) + 1):
            k += 1
```

That is obviously `O(n^6)` and even `θ(n^6)` (big Theta).

<sub>You can compute `k` more directly but I guess `k += 1` is just a placeholder here.</sub>